# grep capture python function definition

Tags: python, grep

I have tried:

```
$ grep -Po "def[[:space:]]+\K(.*)\(" code.py
```

The output should be a list of function names.

I think it should be correct, but it's only capturing one
extra bracket. I would like to get rid off it in the expression
(not postprocessing). Please, explain the syntax, you will use.

Comment: add a sample input and output... I think `grep -Po 'def[[:space:]]+\K[^(]+' code.py` is what you need

Comment: You realize this is missing any arguments to the method, right? So do you just want the function `name` or the entire definition `name(args)` ?

Comment: It seems like the `ast` module might be a better bet for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @pvg I know it exists, but for me quick grep is sufficient. I practise grep.

Comment: @xralf I get that but... There's a thing built into python that reliably parses python. Alternatively, you can look at what [whatnot]tags or your favourite python syntax highlighter has for python regexes.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I want to match function definitions but capture only the function name in capture-group

Comment: `grep` cannot capture groups, as far as I know. Do you eventually intend to use Python's `re` module? If so, practicing with grep is not the best match, as its flavor(s) of regular expressions is (are) different to what Python uses.

Comment: @blubberdiblub he is using `-P` (PCRE), which is very close to python's regex implementation.

Comment: It's still different. For instance `[[:space:]]` would be written `\s` in Python's regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit the "(" from the resulting string by putting it in a lookahead `(?=<expression>)`:

```
grep -Po "def[[:space:]]+\K(.*)(?=\()" code.py
```